# How do I print a request body and headers out of a HTTP Request in Java REST Assured?

Tags: java, rest

While in IntelliJ's debug mode, I found that the value I'm looking for is stored in requestBody and requestHeaders field. However, the problem is that both of these fields are private.

Is there any way to get and print the values of these fields, preferably in Pretty format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `getReader()` method to read the body from an `HttpServletRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RequestLoggingFilter` and specifiy the `LogDetail.HEADERS` parameter to log just the request headers.

See here for the [filter documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#filters) or [the fluent API for logging](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#request-logging).